# Use Display Suite token field in custom block type template

Tags: 8, theming, blocks, display-suite

- I have a custom block type, which uses its own theme template.
- I have a display suite token field `link_card_edit_block`
- It just uses HTML and tokens to create a link.
- I want to use that field in my block type template.
- Without the custom template, the field shows up.
- If I add `{{ content }}` in the custom block template, the field shows.
- But I can't figure out how show that field individually.

Here is what I have tried:

```
{{ content['#block_content'].field_link_card_edit_block.value }}
{{ content['#block_content'].field_link_card_edit_block[0] }}
{{ content['#block_content'].field_link_card_edit_block }}
{{ content.field_link_card_edit_block.value }}
{{ content.field_link_card_edit_block[0] }}
{{ content.field_link_card_edit_block }}
```

All of them produce nothing.

Comment: You probably copy-and-pasted these snippets from examples without Display Suites, but now you have additional regions in the display mode and you need a longer path to find the field inside of {{ content }}.

Comment: I did not copy and paste these. I was experimenting. What might those longer paths be?

Comment: This depends on how you've configured the Display Suite options for this display mode. As far as I can remember enabling the module adds already a default layer. Use kint() or Xdebug.

Comment: It would help to have an example of what a path would look like. Where would I use kint()? What would I be trying to find with it? What would it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My teammate figured this out:

{{ content['dynamic_token_field:block_content-link_card_edit_block'] }}